# Dual boot Windows 10 after initial Arch Linux instilation

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, grub

I recently built myself a desktop for personal use, and initially installed Arch Linux as my primary os (on an NVME drive), being a bit of a gamer I eventually came to the conculsion that I needed a Windows instillation too. I installed Windows 10 to a 500gb partition on my HDD (my secondary drive).

Tired of manually switching boot order in the BIOS whenever I needed to use windows I've recently attempted to make grub boot windows as well, this is where my problem begins.

Grub only shows a boot entry for arch, although os-prober returns the windows boot manager location. I've disabled fast boot and tried making manual entries for grub, still it only shows Arch for boot options no matter what I do before running install-grub (even to /dev/sda and /dev/nvme0n1 sequentially).

Partition tables (fdisk -l output):

> Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors 
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: gpt
>   Disk identifier: 1412B5DB-A22B-4957-B915-EC6B912D8833
>   
>   Device            Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
>   /dev/nvme0n1p1     2048   1002048   1000001 488.3M EFI System
>   /dev/nvme0n1p2  1003520  34557948  33554429    16G Linux swap
>   /dev/nvme0n1p3 34557952 488397134 453839183 216.4G Linux filesystem
>   
>   
>   Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disklabel type: gpt
>   Disk identifier: BF345208-15FD-454F-8252-9963AC133C5C
>   
>   Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
>   /dev/sda1       2048      34815      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
>   /dev/sda2      34816  524290047  524255232  250G Microsoft basic data
>   /dev/sda3  524290048 5860533134 5336243087  2.5T Linux filesystem
>   
>   One weird thing is in BIOS, it states the windows boot entry as being on my NVME drive, which I'm assuming Windows detected as an ESP and automatically installed its boot manager to.

EDIT:

So update-grub is a Debian thing, Arch uses grub-mkconfig, which I can run succesfully, and the following is part of the output:

> #### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
>
> Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
>   menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class >os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-CAB4-D072' {
>          insmod part_gpt
>          insmod fat
>          if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
>            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  CAB4-D072
>          else
>            search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root CAB4-D072
>          fi
>          chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
>   }
>
> #### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober

Yet when I boot from either the "arch" or "grub" boot options (both on my NVME drive) from the BIOS, the only grub entry is still arch.

Comment: Do you have enabled UEFI in your system? And are the boot drives in GPT partitioned table?

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo update-grub`, if you haven’t already.

I always forget to do that... ;)

Comment: Also, running install-grub will overwrite your previously made changes to grub if done on the same disk...

Comment: I've been using install-grub because update grub returns command not found, possible fix there?

Comment: @SamP perhaps this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found/418670#418670

Comment: on Arch it's grub-mkconfig

Answer (score -1):

Using this command on Arch added Windows 10 to grub alongside Arch.

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

Comment: Please explain how this command line solved the problem.   Do not respond in comments;  [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.